# Laravel use of concat with pluck method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, concatenation, pluck

I am using Laravel.5.3 and below is my query

```
$ProjectManagers = Employees::where("designation" , 1)
->pluck(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) AS name'),'id');
```

which throws an error that

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty

May i know if this is the correct method  ?

if i dont use contact and use like

```
$ProjectManagers = Employees::where("designation" , 1)->pluck('first_name','id');
```

which is working correct and giving me result

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [8] => Punit
        )

)
```

**Expected Result :**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [8] => Punit Gajjar
        )

)
```

where first name and last name are concatenated.

Comment: change `->pluck('first_name','id');` to `->pluck('name','id');?

Comment: @martincarlin87  : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Comment: hmm, was just a guess off the top of my head, I imagine `name` would have to be in there somewhere since that's the alias that is used in the query. The only other thing I can think of is `$ProjectManagers = Employees::select([DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) AS name")])->where('designation', 1)->pluck('name', 'id');`. I haven't used pluck so not sure if you can ask for more than one column, an alternative seems to be to use `->only("id", "name")->toArray()`

Comment: yeah it works thanks , , correct one is `$ProjectManagers = Employees::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS name"),'id')->where('designation', 1)->pluck('name', 'id');`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try changing the eloquent query to:

```
$ProjectManagers = Employees::select(
            DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS name"), 'id')
            ->where('designation', 1)
            ->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 61):

The most elegant solution is to create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

Open your **Employees** class (model) and add an accessor function:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

After that, just simply use:

```
$ProjectManagers = Employees::where('designation', 1)->get()->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's worth noting (though, maybe just my stupidity) that to access all records with the mutator you must write `Employees::all()->pluck('full_name', 'id')`. Notice the `all()`. I negated that because I didn't have a well clause, but Laravel queries the database on the first call causing it to search the database for `full_name`.

Comment: Great use of the getFooAttribute() accessor.

Comment: This is the best soluton

Comment: Wow! Impressive. This worked for me and I feel this is very elegant!

Comment: This is a good solution as long as you have only a few hundreds of records in your database. For thousands of records, this takes ages. The well performing solutions are those that don't use accessors, but a concat() on the database level.

Comment: Be aware of the get() call which usually is not there when you use the pluck.

Answer (score 4):

if your column is nullable then you should try this

convert the `NULL` values with empty string by `COALESCE`

```
$ProjectManagers = Employees::select(
            DB::raw("CONCAT(COALESCE(`first_name`,''),' ',COALESCE(`last_name`,'')) AS name"),'id')
            ->where('designation', 1)
            ->pluck('name', 'id')
            ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

**I also faced a problem like that with join query here is the solution of my problem**

```
$studentDegree = Student::leftJoin('degree','degree.student_id','=','student.id')
->select(
      DB::raw("CONCAT(student.name,'-',degree.name) AS name_degree"),
      'student.id'
)->lists('name_degree','id');
```